# Is it possible to get File Explorer to remember open tabs for next time you start it?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

I've been using an add-in for Windows File Explorer called QtTabBar for years. The main benefit it gave me was tabs.

I've just upgraded my PC from Windows 10 to Windows 11, which has tabs in File Explorer. However, unlike QtTabBar, when I close and reopen File Explorer, it just opens with a single view (without a tab showing). QtTabBar used to reopen my tabs, which was very useful.

Is this possible without installing QtTabBar?

Comment: You need a third party addition for Windows Explorer (I do not know one) or use xPlorer2 or like.

Comment: @John Thanks for the comment. If I'm going to use a 3rd party addition, I might as well stick with QtTabBar, as I'm used to it, and it does plenty of other things besides the tabs. I just wondered if there was a way to do it without an addition. Thanks again

Comment: For that same reason, I still use Open Shell Menu, https://open-shell.github.io/Open-Shell-Menu/, to replace the Start menu -- MS repeatedly changes the appearance and functionality, as in Explorer, without providing a consistent, well-designed interface.

Comment: I was so happy Windows added multiple tabs in Windows 11 file explorer after all this time we've been waiting for, and I'm becoming more and more unhappy because of such things...